# ¿Se puede cambiar la apariencia del progressbar en TKINTER?

Tags: python

Vereis quiero hacer un reproductor mp3 y esto es lo que llevo:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

#BARRA_PROGRESO
barra=ttk.Progressbar(miFrame_2,orient="horizontal",length=300)
barra.grid(row=1,column=4)
```

Mi pregunta es si puedo cambiar la apariencia de la progressbar

Comment: Depende que quieras cambiar, el fondo y el color de la barra por ejemplo son modificables.

Comment: como se cambia el fondo y el color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El color de fondo, el de la barra y los bordes es modificable customizando el estilo (`ttk.Style`) del widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x200")

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')

s.configure(
    "custom.Horizontal.TProgressbar",
    troughcolor='#5A504E',
    background='#BF00FF',
    darkcolor="#390439",
    lightcolor="#ED28F0",
    bordercolor="black",
    )

bar = ttk.Progressbar(
    root,
    style="custom.Horizontal.TProgressbar",
    orient="horizontal",
    length=500,
    mode="determinate",
    maximum=4,
    value=1)

bar.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para explicar que modifica cada argumento mejor unas cuantas imágenes que explicarlo con palabras (se resalta en rojo lo que modifica cada uno):

- `troughcolor`

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- `background`

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- `darkcolor`

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- `lightcolor`

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- `bordercolor`

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias